# Security Patch 7405 Pulling API 500 internal error logs

Tags: supee-7405, varien, varien-io-file

I've spent hours looking over the internet and cannot figure out where is the issue with the changed PHP lines. Problems only started after successfully updating patch 7405. Website and all other functionality runs fine, we are using an api to pull order to another shipping software resulting in 500 internal error at every pull. I Can't figure out what's going wrong... Looking at the log I get the following errors:

> [error] 493#0: *746 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Varien_File_Csv' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 313" while reading response header from upstream
>
> [error] 493#0: *748 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Varien_File_Csv' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 313" while reading response header from upstream
>
> [error] 493#0: *750 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Varien_File_Csv' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 313" while reading response header from upstream
>
> [error] 493#0: *853 access forbidden by rule, client: request: "POST /app/etc/local.xml HTTP/1.1",
>
> [error] 493#0: *929 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /web/lib/Varien/File/Csv.php on line 93" while reading response header from upstream,
>
> [error] 493#0: *1189 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /web/lib/Varien/File/Csv.php on line 93" while reading response header from
>
> [error] 477#0: *115 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /web/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 684"

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error log I can only see you are missing one PHP file, but this is unrelated to 7405 patch.

Check if you have `lib/Varien/File/Csv.php` file in your Magento installation.

If not just take from a clean install and copy it.

When you say API, do you mean Magento API or custom API?

If you are using a custom API make sure it is 7405 compliant because there where a lot of changes in the order export dataflow.

Comment: So I checked the Csv.php, it was there. Replaced it with a clean copy downloaded directely from magento 1.7.02 version. Problem persists so doesn't look like it is this file. The API software is Ship station and they use their own developed api module on Magento. Worked fine before the security update, like you said it must be something that has to do with order export dataflow. From another thread I saw that 7405 broke the api of magento and a hacky fix was posted, tried it but to no avail. any other suggestions ?

Comment: Just increase your execution time (the other error from your log). Modify max_execution_time in php.ini and set to 600 to make a test.

Comment: That did it thanks! so it looks like the extra security of magento in 7045 add loading time on the server side. Even though I have plenty of memory and cpu available... the added security and extra line of php makes it go over 30 seconds. I changed it to 100 secs on the php.ini and it works just like before